# SocketException: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, smtp

I got this error when I want to send email for Confirm User Email:

"SocketException: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(string hostName, bool justAddresses)"

"SmtpException: Failure sending mail.
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)"

This is my code to send email:

```
public Task SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string subject, string message, bool isMessageHtml = false)
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential()
            {
                UserName = "", // without @gmail.com
                Password = ""
            };

            client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.Host = "smtp@gmail.com";
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            using var emailMessage = new MailMessage()
            {
                To = { new MailAddress(toEmail) },
                From = new MailAddress(""), // with @gmail.com
                Subject = subject,
                Body = message,
                IsBodyHtml = isMessageHtml
            };

            client.Send(emailMessage);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't *smtp@gmail.com* be **smtp.gmail.com**?

Comment: I tried but it did not answer

Comment: The port number for SSL should be 465. 587 is for TLS/STARTTLS.